# how to pass in objects from Angular to backend in a GET request?

Tags: angular, spring, http, get, frontend

I am trying to pass in objects from Angular to backend using GET request, but I am getting null values for all the properties if I am using a custom objects in the back end, what are the correct ways to pass in objects in a GET call?
So here's my code in the UI :

```
 public getRules(lockedFolder: Folder, pageSize: number, requiredCount: boolean, search: AdvancedSearch, filters: AdvancedSearch): Observable<PaginateResults<Rules>> {
        const searchOption = {
            projectId: lockedFolder.projectId,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            requiredCount: requiredCount,
            search: search,
            filters: filters
        };
        return this._http.get<PaginateResults<Rules>>(this._rulesResourceUrl, {params: this.setQueryString(searchOption)});
    }
```

and the setQueryString method is:

```
setQueryString(params: object) {
        let httpParams = new HttpParams();
        if (params) {
            for (const key of Object.keys(params)) {
                httpParams = httpParams.set(key, params[key]);
            }
        }
        return httpParams;
      }
```

and the API method I have :

```
public ResponseEntity<PaginateResults<Rule>> getRules(@RequestParam("projectId") Integer projectId,  
  @RequestParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize, 
@RequestParam("requiredCount") Boolean requiredCount,
 RuleAdvancedSearch search, RuleAdvancedSearch filter) {
```

- I am able to get the primitive types values, which is projectId, pageSize and requiredCount in the backend.
- However, I also want to get the search ( RuleAdvancedSearch Object), BUT the properties are always null for some reason.

The RuleAdvancedSearch have the following fields:

- ruleType
- ruleName
- modelRestriction
- optionRestriction

For example, if I pass in the following to the GET request :

```
{
    "projectId": 123456,
    "pageSize": 100,
    "requiredCount": true,
    "search": {
        "ruleName": "%00ABC"
    }
}
```

I am able to get the projectId, pageSize, requiredCount, but for the search,
 it has null values for all properties, which is not I expect. I expect the ruleName should have "%00ABC", but what I got is :

```
 - ruleType = null
 - ruleName = null
 - modelRestriction = null
 - optionRestriction = null
```

What is the correct way to pass in custom objects to GET request?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there is no way you can pass object to get method, you have to pass via query string.

before passing through the query string check that query string has null value, if has null value exclude it and if not include it in the query string.